# Require / Browserify hoodie in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, browserify, hoodie

My aim is to use hood.ie framework in Angular. Instead of including all the JS files, I would like to use Browserify and require() the dependencies. I cannot find a way to require hoodie (template app for hood.ie uses `<script src="/_api/files/hoodie.js">` which is provided by "hoodie start" command. Is there a way to include it with require()?

My project structure:

```
.
+-- app 
|  +-- app.js
|  +-- index.html
|  +-- main
|  |  +-- index.js
|  |  +-- main.html
|  +-- auth
|  |  +-- index.js
|  |  +-- login.html
+-- dist
|  +-- main
|  |  +-- main.html
|  +-- auth
|  |  +-- index.html 
|  +-- browsified.js
|  +-- index.html
```

The dist directory is built by gulp:

```
var gulp = require('gulp')
var browserify = require('browserify')
var source = require('vinyl-source-stream')
var exec = require('child_process').exec

gulp.task('hoodie-start', ['copy-static', 'browserify'],  function() {
  var child = exec('node ./node_modules/hoodie-server/bin/start --www dist --custom-ports 6001,6002,6003');
  child.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
      console.log(data);
  });
  child.stderr.on('data', function(data) {
      console.log(data);
  });
  return child;
});

gulp.task('browserify', function() {
    var options = {
        entries: ['./app/app.js'],
        extensions: ['.js']
    }
    return browserify(options)
        .bundle()
        .pipe(source('browserified.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'));
});

gulp.task('copy-static', function() {
    return gulp.src(['./app/**/*.html'])
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist')); 
});
```

The package.json file (stripped from irrelevant parts):

```
{
  ...
  "main": "dist/index.html",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "^1.4.8",
    "angular-route": "^1.4.8",
    "hoodie-plugin-angularjs": "^0.1.1",
    "hoodie-plugin-appconfig": "^2.0.1",
    "hoodie-plugin-email": "^1.0.0",
    "hoodie-plugin-users": "^2.2.2",
    "hoodie-server": "^4.0.2"
  },
  "bundleDependencies": [
    "hoodie-plugin-angularjs",
    "hoodie-plugin-appconfig",
    "hoodie-plugin-email",
    "hoodie-plugin-users",
    "hoodie-server"
  ],
  "devDependencies": {
    "browserify": "^13.0.0",
    "gulp": "^3.9.0",
    "vinyl-source-stream": "^1.1.0"
  },
  "hoodie": {
    "plugins": [
      "hoodie-plugin-appconfig",
      "hoodie-plugin-email",
      "hoodie-plugin-users",
      "hoodie-plugin-angularjs"
    ]
  }
}
```

Finally, app.js:

```
var angular = require('angular');
var ngRoute = require('angular-route');

var main = require('./main');
var auth = require('./auth');  

var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute', 'hoodie', main.name, auth.name]); 

app.config([
    '$routeProvider', 'hoodieProvider', function($routeProvider, hoodieProvider) {

        $routeProvider.when('/login', {
            templateUrl: 'auth/login.html',
            controller: 'LoginController'
        });

        $routeProvider.otherwise({
            templateUrl: 'main/main.html',
            controller: 'MainController'
        });

        hoodieProvider.url('http://myapp.com');

    }
]);
```

I planned to take advantage of hoodie-plugin-angularjs, but it is not require()-able either.

Any hints how to plumb it all together?

Comment: I have tried "npm install --save hoodie@next" and then require('hoodie'), but it did not work for some reason. Is this the way to go?

Comment: If you installed the plugin through npm, it should be requireble...

Comment: Could not find hoodie, please find attached the error: http://pastebin.com/K2SWNTwn

Comment: Did you require the client library? https://github.com/hoodiehq/hoodie-client

Comment: "npm install --save hoodie-client" and added 

require('hoodie-client');
require('hoodie');

The same error while running gulp...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you have 2 issues here. First, by looking at the documentation it looks like you need to require the [client](https://github.com/hoodiehq/hoodie-client) library which exposes the `Hoodie` constructor. Second, the `hoodie-plugin-angularjs` library [expects a global `Hoody`](https://github.com/elmarburke/hoodie-plugin-angularjs/blob/master/hoodie.angularjs.js#L194) to be available. Try the following:

```
// app.js

// Make global
var Hoodie = require('hoodie-client');
window.Hoodie = Hoodie;

// Now the plugin knows about Hoodie.
// It will run the side-effect,
// namely registering the angular service 
require('hoodie-plugin-angularjs');

// ... Angular code that uses Hoodie
```

Comment: I think, I accepted the answer little too quickly. The first line, ´var Hoodie = require('hoodie-client');´ worked like a charm. After adding it, I could create the hoodie object manually ´var hoodie = new Hoodie()´, but requiring hoodie-plugin-angularjs actually failed with "Error: Could not find module hoodie-plugin-angularjs" when running "gulp browserify". Is that because it is not a proper CommonJS module?

Comment: It seems like it... I'd look into [browerify-shim](https://github.com/thlorenz/browserify-shim) or otherwise you could fork it and make it compatible with Commonjs.